# Swapping li elements between multiple un-ordered lists using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to allow the user to move the 'post-it' notes from one un-ordered list of tasks to another. Ideally when the user drags the task it should be removed from its current container and appended to the new list.

### Pseudo HTML

```
<ul class="task-bucket" id="backlog-tasks">
    <!-- task a -->
    <!-- task b -->
    <!-- task c -->
</ul>
<ul class="task-bucket" id="do-tasks">
    <!-- task d -->
</ul>
<ul class="task-bucket" id="doing-tasks">
    <!-- task e -->
</ul>
<ul class="task-bucket" id="done-tasks">
    <!-- task f -->
</ul>
```

I'd like for tasks to be draggable between lists, e.g. when **task e** is finished it can be dragged into #done-tasks.

If you have a solution, feel free to build it on top of: http://jsfiddle.net/Zwedh/2/

Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/RD5M6/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){   
    $('.task-bucket').sortable({
        connectWith: '.task-bucket'
    });

    $('.task').draggable({
        connectToSortable: '.task-bucket'
    });
    $('ul', 'li').disableSelection();
})
```

The solution is much simpler than I had originally anticipated!
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery UI's [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)

Comment: Can you give a bit more information on how to move an element between multiple lists.

Comment: I haven't worked with Droppable very much, but it looks like the code on the link I posted has everything you need to get started: call draggable() on the draggable object and droppable() on the droppable objects (the lists) and handle any behaviour in the callback.